# Check a RadButton checkbox within a RadListView ItemTemplate - Client Side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I am simply attempting to set the checkbox of a telerik RadButton that is inside the item template of a RadListView on the client side (with javascript/jquery).

RadListView:

```
<telerik:RadListView runat="server" 
                     ID="parameterList" 
                     OnNeedDataSource="parameterList_NeedDataSource">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <telerik:RadButton ToggleType="CheckBox" 
                           ButtonType="LinkButton"
                           runat="server"
                           ID="chkParameterType" 
                           AutoPostBack="False"
                           Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>
                           CssClass='<%# Eval("ParameterName") + "_button" %>'>
          <ToggleStates>
            <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleCheckboxChecked"/>
            <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleCheckbox" />
          </ToggleStates>
        </telerik:RadButton>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListView>
```

My jquery attempts have been first to try to use telerik's libraries as indicated in [this post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/getting-control-in-a-listview-via-javascript)

```
var listView = $find('<%= parameterList.ClientID %>');
var txbClientObject = $telerik.findControl(listView.get_element().parentNode, 
                                           "chkParameterType").get_value()
var current = txbClientObject.get_value();
```

But `txbClientObject` comes back as unidentified, so `current` breaks with `cannot read property of null`

I've also tried to find the button by classname in straight jquery.  I worry about this because I believe that rendering can be different in different browsers.

```
var button = $("." + name + "_button > input");  //"name" is parameterName
button.prop("checked", true);
```

This does not error, and debugging through it, it finds the button (or span), but also fails to check the box.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the event that you run this code on? It must be at least the Sys.Application.Load event, otherwise the control instances may still be undefined.

Also, you have an additional `%>` at the Text property which would break the compilation.

Then, findControl() will give you the control instance, you do not need the get_value() call there.

What you should consider is which button you want, since the ListView can have several items and this will give you the first.

So, here is something that worked for me:

```
<telerik:RadListView runat="server" 
                             ID="parameterList" 
                             OnNeedDataSource="parameterList_NeedDataSource">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadButton ToggleType="CheckBox" 
                                           ButtonType="LinkButton"
                                           runat="server"
                                           ID="chkParameterType" 
                                           AutoPostBack="False"
                                           Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                                           CssClass='<%# Eval("ParameterName") + "_button" %>'>
                            <ToggleStates>
                                <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleCheckboxChecked"/>
                                <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleCheckbox" />
                            </ToggleStates>
                        </telerik:RadButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadListView>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="get first button" OnClientClick="getFirstButton(); return false;" runat="server" />
        <script>
            function getFirstButton() {
                var listView = $find('<%= parameterList.ClientID %>');
                var txbClientObject = $telerik.findControl(listView.get_element().parentNode,
                                                           "chkParameterType");
                var current = txbClientObject.get_value();
                alert(txbClientObject.get_checked());
                alert(txbClientObject.get_text());
                txbClientObject.set_checked(true);
            }
        </script>
```

Here is a more complete sample that will show you how you can use CSS classes to get any desired element and will also provide valid HTML by specifying the LayoutTemplate:

```
<telerik:RadListView runat="server"
                             ID="parameterList"
                             OnNeedDataSource="parameterList_NeedDataSource"
                             ItemPlaceholderID="theItemPlaceHolder">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="theItemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td class="buttonCell">
                        <telerik:RadButton ToggleType="CheckBox" 
                                           ButtonType="LinkButton"
                                           runat="server"
                                           ID="chkParameterType" 
                                           AutoPostBack="False"
                                           Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                                           CssClass='<%# Eval("ParameterName") + "_button" %>'>
                            <ToggleStates>
                                <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleCheckboxChecked"/>
                                <telerik:RadButtonToggleState PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleCheckbox" />
                            </ToggleStates>
                        </telerik:RadButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadListView>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="get third button" OnClientClick="getThirdButton();return false;" runat="server" />
        <script>
            function getThirdButton() {
                var listView = $find('<%= parameterList.ClientID %>');
                var buttonCells = $telerik.$(".buttonCell", listView.get_element().parentNode);
                var txbClientObject = $telerik.findControl(buttonCells[2],
                                                           "chkParameterType");
                var current = txbClientObject.get_value();
                alert(txbClientObject.get_checked());
                alert(txbClientObject.get_text());
                txbClientObject.set_checked(true);
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Copy paste error on the extra `%>`.  This looks excellent, i'll give it a go.

Comment: Your second example was just what I needed.  I change the css class for each button.  So i moved the change to the td element and found the control per your example regardless of number.